# Will I be able to use a wordpress site domain as a django website on a VPS?

Tags: django, wordpress, web-deployment

I deleted all the files and folders associated with the Wordpress site I intend to write from scratch using standard HTML, JavaScript, CSS and with Django framework. My question is if I can use this domain with this newly created site in a VPS.

At first I had erased the files and folders and recreated it with the Django app right onto the Wordpress structure, and that does not seem to be working. I am most likely doing something wrong anyways, but I am after the right way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain names are separate from web servers (such as your VPS), CMS (e.g. WordPress) or a framework (e.g. Django). So there is no problem using that same domain name for your new website with Django.

However, you'll need to reconfigure your VPS to run Django. Better if you reinstall your VPS with Django. Follow the guide provided by your VPS to install Django properly. This includes configuring the web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx), setting up a database, and properly linking your domain to the new server.

Comment: I was able to install Django on the server even though I already had done so under another application as well as python. I ran the server through the terminal, and it still up under it's ip address, but I am still unable to visit the domain. I have gone to the Wordpress domain location to change the DNS and have done so. It has been a few hours and no change. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yes, you probably didn't point the web server to your domain name. For example, check this tutorial and see which steps you missed related to the domain name: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: I assigned the domain to my VPS as an add-on. My assumption is that I will have to re-install Django inside of my domain's folder again, even though I can just copy and paste the files from the previous directory. I will probably just redo the Django tutorial again. Before assigning domain, I was able to see my other website's homepage in the new domain, and I don't know why, and the polls and admin page worked temporarily. Sorry as I am new to backend development.

Comment: Just to be clear it was the other VPS website that is currently up on the same VPS(same ip address) and not the previous domain of the wordpress site. Also, I believe I completed mostly everything expect server configuration and that is what I believe I need the most help on, since the site partially worked, even though it was displaying the other website.